# Adjust margins of figure notes

Tags: floats, footnotes, minipage, landscape

[image: Picture of the output]

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[h]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Figures/Figurex0303bldprsr.pdf}
    \caption{Hypertension} \label{Figurex0303bldprsr}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{0.2cm}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Figures/Figurex0303hepatitis.pdf}
    \caption{Hepatitis} \label{Figurex0303hepatitis}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{0.2cm}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Figures/Figurex0303diabetes.pdf}
    \caption{Diabetes} \label{Figurex0303diabetes}
\end{subfigure}
\caption[]{(Continued)}
\label{Figurex0303-cont}
% \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
%     \footnotesize \textit{Notes.} Coefficient plots for health and health-related behavior outcomes (vertical axis) based on estimating equation (2) with different bandwidth sizes (horizontal axis).
% \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape
```

I am trying to adjust the margins around the notes in the minipage. for some reason, the margin is really long, although I made it only 0.9 of line width. This is in landscape mode. Other figures in the document are Ok. Not sure what is the problem with this one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an MWE *from `\documentclass... to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have done and whate the problem is. What is the document class? We don't have any of your code for figures.

Comment: When you work with `landscape`, `\textwidth` is not valid. Use `\linewidth`, instead.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved @Celdor

Comment: Note that `\hspace{0.2cm)` is equivalent to `\hspace{0.2cm}\space`.. Almost every line which ends with `}` adds an extra `\space`.  Use `}%` instead. Better yet, use `\end{subfigure}\hfill`.  (One exception is `\caption` which begins and ends aieh `\par`.)

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo